# How to select almost equally distributed classes in training,validation,test samples?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am working on `MNIST Sign Language` dataset to classify images using `Keras`. There are 24 different classes in the dataset. But the problem is that the distribution of classes of very different.

I used `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` to `stratify=df['label']` but still some classes have 5% while others have 3% of the whole data. How can I make them to choose a data that is around 4% distributed among the classes.

My `test_df` has 7172 rows and 785 columns one of which is a `label` column and remaining `784` are grayscale pixel values `(28*28)`

```
test_df = pd.read_csv(TEST_PATH)

# shuffle and split validation,test data
test_df = test_df.sample(frac=1.0,random_state=SEED).iloc[:2000,:] # shuffle the whole data, get first 2000 rows
val_df,test_df = train_test_split(test_df,test_size=0.5,random_state=SEED,stratify=test_df['label'])
# stratify the labels so that distribution of classes is almost same

# extract pixels and labels for both validation,test data
X_val = val_df.drop('label',axis=1).values.reshape((val_df.shape[0],28,28))/255.0 # validation images
y_val = val_df['label'].ravel() # validation label

X_test = test_df.drop('label',axis=1).values.reshape((test_df.shape[0],28,28))/255.0 # test images
y_val = test_df['label'].ravel() # test label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line enables you to have a uniform distribution with val and test. you can play also with the number of samples

```
SEED = 42
n_classes = 24

test_df = pd.read_csv(TEST_PATH)

test_df = [test_df.loc[test_df.label==i].sample(n=int(2000/n_classes),random_state=SEED) for i in test_df.label.unique()]
test_df = pd.concat(test_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

val_df,test_df = train_test_split(test_df,test_size=0.5,random_state=SEED,stratify=test_df['label'])
```

Comment: this grant you equal dist label. check pd.value_counts(y_val) ... you can't have 1000 if you select 2000 sample and have 24 classes. play with n

Comment: there are always 4 short. 2500 gives 2496 images and 2000 gives 996 for each. Will try to change `n`

Comment: to grant an equal distribution this is what happens